# How does one generally use partial function in logical statements?

Tags: logic, computability, formal-languages, coding-theory, turing-machines

How does one generally use partial function in logical statements? How it's done in practice?

Specifically, let $M$ by a Turing machine, $f_M:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}$ the characteristic function which corresponds to $M$, $U$ a universal Turing machine and $f_U$ the corresponding function which for given input takes values in $\{0,1\}$. Let the variables $x,\alpha$ be bit strings

Can I write $\forall x.\ \exists\alpha.\ f_U(\alpha,x)=f_M(x)$?

The problem is that for $x$ where the Turing machine loops, $f_M(x)$ doesn't even take a value and the sentence "$f_U(\alpha,x)=f_M(x)$" amounts to "$\%!?=!?\$?$".

And I don't even know how to prevent things from going wrong, because if I cautiously write

$\forall x.\ (f_M(x)\in\{0,1\}\implies \exists\alpha.\ f_U(\alpha,x)=f_M(x))$

puts the problem just on $f_M(x)\in\{0,1\}$, which can similarly just not make any sense as $f(x)$ might not have a value.

---

Edit: My initial motivation for the question comes from 'Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach - Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak'

http://www.math.sc.edu/~cooper/math778C/abct.pdf

In particular

[image]

How would one formally write the statement "forall $x$ ...  such that $U(x,\alpha)=M_\alpha(x)$"? In the book, $M$ is previously define as a tupple $\langle \Gamma,\Sigma, Q,\delta,\dots$, so $M(x)$ here is just "suggestive notation" for the output of $M$ running on $x$. That's also why I went over to the characteristic (partial?) functions to formulate the question.

And I don't necessarily need to use the characteristic function - I've tried (and I think succeeded) in recursively defining a partial function (which I call $\mathrm{run}_M$) out of the transition function $\delta$ of a Turing machine $M$. But it's still a partial function and I can't just write $\forall x.\ \mathrm{run}_M(x)=$ because I'd first have to introduce a bounded quantifier to function notation $\mathrm{run}_M(x)$ to make sense.

Comment: It is not so clear to me what you are asking. If you want to "formalize" Turing machine theory you need the language of set thory: you have to speak of *functions*. In set theory functions are sets and this does not necessarly implies that a function $f : N \rightarrow  N$ must be evertwhere defined. $f$ is a *relation* i.e. a subset of $N \times N$. Saying that $f$ and $g$ are equal means that for each $a \in f$, $a=<x,y>$, we have $a \in g$ ...

Comment: One thing you could do is replace equality with [Kleene equality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleene+equality). Another option would be to replace it with "existential equality", which returns false unless all the inputs exist. Unfortunately, there is not a lot of good information out there on this topic.

Comment: @user18921: Ah, interesting link. But what I talked with Denis applies here too: The link says *In the setting of partial functions and operations, saying that an equality between terms such as $s = t$ is a Kleene equality means that it asserts that if either side of the equality is defined"* Now if $a$ and $b$ are legal input strings written using the alphabet of Turing machines $M$ and $N$ respectively, how to judge if $M(a)=N(b)$ is "defined"? How can I generally speak of such relations, given that the Halting problem prevents me to judge if $M(a)$ and $N(b)$ reduce to some values?

Answer (score 2):

(1) On the question of how "in practice" to handle equations involving partial functions, here's a quote from Cutland's classic text *Computability* (CUP), at p.3, explaining a common device:

> Often in computability we shall encounter functions, or expressions
>   involving functions, that are not always defined. In such situations the
>   following notation is very useful. Suppose that $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ and $\beta(\mathbf{x})$ are 
>   expressions involving the variables $\mathbf{x} = (x_1 ... x_n)$. Then we write
>   $$\alpha(\mathbf{x}) \simeq \beta(\mathbf{x}) $$
>
> to mean that for any $\mathbf{x}$, the expressions $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ and  $\beta(\mathbf{x})$ are either both
>   defined, or both undefined, and if defined they are equal.

(2) Suppose you want now more formally to logically regiment arguing with function expressions which may take no value, so e.g.  $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ is undefined. [NB Importantly, this *doesn't* mean that in such a case  $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ is nonsense like ?&%!. We may perfectly well understand the sense of the functional expression, understand what it is instructing us to do, and it is exactly because we understand it that we can work out that it fails to output a value]. Classical logic -- where, by stipulation, all terms denote -- obviously won't do. So we need a so-called *free* logic (i.e.  a logic free from existence assumptions). See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/‎ for a helpful introduction and review of some of the options here.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, following Peter Smith's remark, is to avoid *terms* (in this case : function symbols) and use instead a predicate (in computability theory we have it: Kleene's $T$ predicate).

We have a similar example in (formal) *arithmetic*. We define :

> $a|b$ iff $\exists c \ (ac=b)$

so we may call $c$ the "quotient" of $b$ and $a$.

We may not (in classical logic) add to the language a *function* $\text {quot}(x,y)$ such that $\text{quot}(a,b)=c$ exactly because in $\mathbb{N}$ the operation of division is **not always** defined, i.e.

> $\text{quot}(0,1)$ is *undefined*.

We may solve the problem with a predicate $\text{Quot}(a,b,c)$ that holds exactly when $c=a|b$.

In this case :

> for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\text{Quot}(0,1,n)$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably reversed your quantifiers, you probably mean: $\exists\alpha, \forall x, f_U(\alpha,x)=f_M(x)$.

About the "undefined" issue, it is not really a big deal to write an equality in case both are undefined. We can consider that "undefined" is a special value often written $\bot$, and a partial function is in fact a total function with values in $\{0,1,\bot\}$. It is just important to keep in mind that you cannot define a computable function $g$ by using "if $f(x)=\bot$ then return $1$", because if the machine $f$ you simulate does not terminate, then $g$ also does not terminate.
That is why some people prefer to write "$f$ loops on $x$ " instead of $f(x)=\bot$, to keep in mind this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right in the first line, I swapped the quantifiers. I don't quite understand how your suggestion is logically consistent. Okay, so we know of the Halting problem, so we can't know of all machines if they halt. In the case of the function *If $x=4$, then do a) go to "b)", b) go to "a)* I can judge that it will loop forever and assign the $⊥$ value to that function at $4$. But given that I know I can't judge "undefined" for all machines I can write down, how is that a valid procedure. I mean you say *set 'else: ⊥'*, but I can't determine when 'else' applies!?

Comment: It is allowed to write "if $f(x)=1$ return $\bot$", it is only the converse that is problematic.
It is not because you can solve the halting for a particular example that you can do it in general. What about the machine "Look for a proof of Goldbach conjecture, stop if you find one" does it stop? The only "rule" to remember is that when defining function, if at one point you need to evaluate the outcome of a Turing machine to compute your result, then you have to return $\bot$ whenever this Turing machine returns $\bot$.

Comment: Maybe your confusion comes from the fact that you think things like "$\forall x f_M(x)=f_N(x)$" should be decidable. It's not the case, since it would need in particular to be able to solve the Halting problem. These equations are just mathematical facts, not things we are proving via Turing Machines.